How can I add a summary field to an external link?
I have a page with a content and child pages. These child pages were built with a topic list builder that has a set of links. Each link has a URL field and a Link text. Each one of these links also have a summary to explain what they are about. However, two of these links are external and don't have the option of adding a summary. Is there a way to add a summary to these external links across the website? I am using a theme but I'm not sure how to check it to see if there's a problem in there. I have multiple pages that are missing summaries for their external links.
Sorry for any confusion, I'm still very new to Drupal!
